# HTML 5 and images map

Tags: html, image, html5-canvas

Anyone knows how to accomplish such a thing

http://www.jarzebinowe.pl/mieszkania.html  (you need to choose floor ...)

in html5?

It's about choosing the apartment, lights, etc. ..
Top how would one image was processed by HTML5 so that was the result

I'm sorry for being so strange and laconic question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try the html `map` element**

You probably can achieve your "drill-down" into a building more simply by using html `map` which will let your users click on a portion of an image and link to a new more specific image.

Here's a reference:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

**[Edit with a fancier display with canvas.]**

Here's code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/BbCJx/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:15px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var floorplan=document.getElementById("floorplan");
    var planCtx=floorplan.getContext("2d");
    planCtx.font="24px Arial";
    planCtx.fillStyle="red";

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var lastWindow=-1;
    var plan=new Image();
    var outside=new Image();
    outside.onload=function(){
        plan.onload=function(){
            ctx.drawImage(outside,0,0);
        }
        plan.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/inside.jpg";
    }
    outside.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/outside.png";

    var windows=[]
    windows.push({top:66, left: 70, bottom:111, right:111, floorplan:0, apartment:"3a"});
    windows.push({top:66, left:139, bottom:111, right:183, floorplan:0, apartment:"3b"});
    windows.push({top:66, left:211, bottom:111, right:255, floorplan:0, apartment:"3c"});
    windows.push({top:153, left: 70, bottom:196, right:111, floorplan:1, apartment:"2a"});
    windows.push({top:153, left:139, bottom:196, right:183, floorplan:1, apartment:"2b"});
    windows.push({top:153, left:211, bottom:196, right:255, floorplan:1, apartment:"2c"});
    windows.push({top:239, left:139, bottom:283, right:182, floorplan:2, apartment:"1a"});

    function selectWindow(x,y){
        var w;
        var isInWindow=false;
        for(var i=0;i<windows.length;i++){
            w=windows[i];
            if(x>w.left && x<w.right && y>w.top && y<w.bottom){
               isInWindow=true;
               if(i!=lastWindow){
                   planCtx.clearRect(0,0,floorplan.width,floorplan.height);
                   planCtx.drawImage(plan,0,0);
                   planCtx.fillText("Apt: "+w.apartment+", Plan: "+w.floorplan,70,25);
                   lastWindow=i;
               } 
               break;
            }
        }
        if(!isInWindow){ planCtx.clearRect(0,0,floorplan.width,floorplan.height); };
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      $("#movelog").html("Move: "+ canMouseX + " / " + canMouseY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here
      selectWindow(canMouseX,canMouseY);

    }

    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Mouse over a window to see it's floorplan</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
    <canvas id="floorplan" width=300 height=300></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```